# Generating survival times for a piecewise constant hazard model with two change points

Tags: r, distributions, survival, random-generation

When there are two change points in  a piecewise constant hazard model then the density function becomes some triangle exponential distribution. In this situation I can't generate the survival time from the CDF using probability integral transformation. Can any one help me to generate the survival time from this model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two basic approaches to generating data with piecewise constant hazard: inversion of the cumulative hazard and the composition method.

1. **Inversion of the cumulative hazard** - essentially the inverse CDF method. Since $F(t) = 1-\exp(-H(t))$. If $U \sim Unif(0,1)$, then $F(X) = U$ is equivalent to $1-\exp(-H(X)) = U$, so $X=H^{-1}(-\log(1-U))$. You can also note that $-\log(1-U) \sim Exp(1)$, so you can apply the inverse cumulative hazard to an exponential random variable.
   The cumulative hazard is piecewise linear for your case, and should be easy to invert.

*Edit* (more detail): with two change-points, the hazard is:
$$h(t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} f_1 , & 0\leq t\leq t_1\\ 
                                f_2, & t_1 < t \leq t_2\\
                                f_3, & t > t_2 \end{matrix}\right.$$
The cumulative hazard is:
$$H(t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} f_1 t , & 0\leq t\leq t_1\\ 
                                f_1 t_1 + f_2(t-t_1), & t_1 < t \leq t_2\\
                                f_1t_1 + f_2(t_2-t_1) + f_3(t-t_2), & t > t_2 \end{matrix}\right.$$
The inverse of the cumulative hazard is:
$$H^{-1}(x) =  \left\{ \begin{matrix} x/f_1 , & 0\leq x\leq f_1t_1\\ 
                                t_1 + (x-f_1t_1)/f_2, & f_1t_1 < x \leq f_1t_1 + f_2(t_2-t_1)\\
                                t_2 + (x-f_1t_1-f_2(t_2-t_1))/f_3, & x > f_1t_1 + f_2(t_2-t_1)\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now generate an exponentially distributed random variable, and plug it in into $H^{-1}$.
*End edit*

2. The **Composition method** uses the fact that if $X_1$ has hazard $h_1$, and $X_2$ has hazard $h_2$, then $X=\min(X_1,X_2)$ has hazard  $h=h_1+h_2$. You can represent your piecewise constant hazard as a sum of hazards that are constant on an interval and 0 outside. Generate a value $X_i$ for each interval (it could be $\infty$, since the resulting distributions are not necessarily proper), and take their minimum.

*Edit* (more detail): with the above notation, the composition hazards are
$$h_1(t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} f_1 , & 0\leq t\leq t_1\\ 
                                0, & t > t_1 \end{matrix}\right.$$
$$h_2(t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} f_2 , & t_1 < t\leq t_2\\ 
                                0, & \text{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.$$
$$h_3(t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} f_3 , & t_2< t\\ 
                                0, & \text{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.$$
You can easily calculate the CDF or the cumulative hazard for each of these hazards.

[One resource with R-Code](http://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/technicalreports/tr-2010-003.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm talking about the density function which takes value f1 in the range 0 to t1, value f2 for the range t1 to t2, and f3 for more than t2. In this situation, can I use the 2nd approach? I know the first approach is more applicable, but I can't derive the CDF for this complicated function.

Comment: Thank you so much Aniko for your such detail suggestion. Great Support!!

Comment: @Aniko how would the Composition method be applied to a truncated piecewise exponential?

Comment: @user43290 A simple method for generating any truncated distribution is to generate the untruncated version, then throw away all values outside the range of truncation. If the truncation rate is high, then this is not efficient, and one could work out the component hazards more precisely. They would depend on the probability of truncation.